# Parse WCF response to custom object

Tags: c#, wcf

Please see the code below:

```
public Form1()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            Person p1 = s1.GetPerson();
        }
```

The compile time error I get is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'app.ServiceReference1.Person' to 'WcfService1.Person'.  I understand the reason for this error.  There is a Person object on the server and a person object on the client and they are in different namespaces.

How do you get round this.  I can't just ask the WCF Server developer to ship me the Person class.

I am looking for something like this for a WCF Web Service: [JSON not parsed into custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549052/json-not-parsed-into-custom-object)

I don't understand why the framework desterilises the XML returned by the WCF web service.  The whole point of WCF is that it is suppose to be interoperable.

Comment: I would suggest looking at both answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112181/wcf-returning-objects-to-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service is provided in-house, providers should be providing you the data contracts too, at least in a dll.

Otherwise, you can create your service reference via visual studios Service Referance Generator tool, and it will create the right data contracts for you.

If you are writing your own service, make sure you've created your dto objects with necessary attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int SampleField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How will it: "create the right data contracts for you"? It does not create the Person class.

Comment: Well, it should. The `Person` class is an envelope object between service and client. Hence the properties of it should be provided either in a library, or from a wsdl file. If it is provided by only the wsdl then the Service Reference generator tool should take care of them.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you provide it in a WSDL file?

Comment: When you publish your wcf service the wsdl automatically gets generated. Follow the url that you made the publish, and you'll have it. -if you are doing it right.

Comment: I understand that, but show would you get the WSDL person values on the client and load them into an object on the client side? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Provided all the object properties are named identically you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy the values to your local object, or alternatively just do it manually:

```
public Form1()
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var dto = s1.GetPerson();
    var p1 = new Person()
    {
        x = dto.x,
        y = dto.y,
        z = dto.z
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Automapper reference.  +1.